# My search function does not work

Tags: search, twitter

```
 var cat = prompt("What Do You Want To Tweet??!");

 if(cat.length >= 140)
 {
 confirm("Sorry but your Tweet was over the 140 character limit by: " + (cat.length - 140));
 confirm("You need to resubmit a Tweet that is not over the 140 Character limit");
 }
 else{
confirm("Success, Your Tweet has been posted!");
 }
 //scan for websites

 if (cat.search(" www ", " http ", ".com"))
 {

 }
 else{
 confirm("We have Detected a URL in your Tweet");   
 }
```

---

My code works up until I try to "tweet" a website. if I type www or .com as a tweet, it will tell me it has detected a url which is good. BUT when I type xxxxxx www xxxxxx (x being anythingelse) it wont detect the url

Comment: please tag it with JavaScript, this is not Java.

Comment: Could be Java.  Write a class called `var`, and appropriate methods called `prompt` and `confirm`.  Probably isn't.  Tagging a question with the correct language would make it more likely to attract the correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My search "function" does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716055/my-search-function-does-not-work)