# My search "function" does not work

Tags: javascript, search

```
 var cat = prompt("What Do You Want To Tweet??!");

 if(cat.length >= 140)
{
confirm("Sorry but your Tweet was over the 140 character limit by: " + (cat.length - 140));
confirm("You need to resubmit a Tweet that is not over the 140 Character limit");
}
else{
confirm("Success, Your Tweet has been posted!");
}
//scan for websites

if (cat.search(" www ", " http ", ".com"))
{

}
else{
confirm("We have Detected a URL in your Tweet");   
}
```

---

My code works up until I try to "tweet" a website. if I type www or .com as a tweet, it will tell me it has detected a url which is good. BUT when I type xxxxxx www xxxxxx (x being anythingelse) it wont detect the url.

Comment: I haven't even read your question, and I probably wont unless you reformat your code and make it more readable. Use proper indentation please.

Comment: I would change the logic a little. CHeck this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s7db3x5/1 - basically check for the keywords _before_ confirming the success message - also, remove the space bfore and after `www` and `http`

Comment: I also recommend to read the [**documentation** of `search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search). E.g. it only takes one argument, which is supposed to be a regular expression. The others you pass (`" http "` and `".com"`) are simply ignored.

Comment: When I submit a question it tells me to put code in code form and to indent. But it wont let me indent, it just takes me to the bottom of the page. I just space each line of code 3 times to make it code.

Comment: So if I type `://its.bad.yo`, I'd get right through.

Answer (score 0):

You could do more accurate search by using jQuery. The '.inArray()' function should do the trick.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.inArray demo</title>
    <style>
        div {
            color: blue;
        }
        span {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>"John" found at <span></span></div>
    <div>4 found at <span></span></div>
    <div>"Karl" not found, so <span></span></div>
    <div>"Pete" is in the array, but not at or after index 2, so <span></span></div>
    <script>
        var arr = [ 4, "Pete", 8, "John" ];
        var $spans = $( "span" );
        $spans.eq( 0 ).text( jQuery.inArray( "John", arr ) );
        $spans.eq( 1 ).text( jQuery.inArray( 4, arr ) );
        $spans.eq( 2 ).text( jQuery.inArray( "Karl", arr ) );
        $spans.eq( 3 ).text( jQuery.inArray( "Pete", arr, 2 ) );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regular expressions

```
var cat = prompt("What Do You Want To Tweet??!"),
    expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi,
    regex = new RegExp(expression);
if(cat.length >= 140) {
    confirm("Sorry but your Tweet was over the 140 character limit by: " + (cat.length - 140));
    confirm("You need to resubmit a Tweet that is not over the 140 Character limit");
}
else{
    confirm("Success, Your Tweet has been posted!");
}
//scan for websites

if (cat.match(regex)) {
    confirm("We have dectected a URL in your Tweet");
}
else{
   confirm("no URL");   
}
```